# Python web application project structure and docker support

Tags: python, deployment, configuration, flask, docker

## Description

For instance, I have a following flask project structure:

```
├ project_root/
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── docs
├── requirements.txt
├── yourapp
│   ├── templates/
│   ├── static/
│   ├── migrations/
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── app1/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── controllers.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── models.py
│   ├── app2/
│   │   └── ...
│   └── app.py
└── tests/
```

And I have following requirements:

1. I would like to deploy it with gunicorn behind nginx, with a rabbitmq and celery and postgresql as database. Nginx serves static files from `yourapp/static`
2. I would like to have all configuration be the part of my codebase, for instance all nginx, gunicorn and other configs should be placed somewhere in the same git repository.
3. I would like to use a docker and have following docker images: web-app, postgresql, nginx, rabbitmq and celery-worker.
4. I would like to be able to build all docker images from this git repository
5. I would like to use Dockerfiles

## Question

**Where should I put configuration files and Dockerfiles if I want to meet all these requirements?**

## Additional information

I have some thoughts, but it's not clear. For instance I know, that I actually don't need a Dockerfile for postgresql image, I can use volume-only container and postgres image from Docker hub.

The main problem, that I can't solve is a interference of the nginx and application scopes: static files should be visible for nginx's Dockerfile and whole flask application also should be visible for gunicorn's Dockerfile, but I can't put 2 Dockerfiles in the same folder.

The other problem, that I would like to have folder with flask code(yourapp) be separated from the configurations folder, and all configuration files(nginx, gunicorn, celery) should be stored in the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `docker-compose` and do something like this example `docker-compose.yml`

```
web-app:
    build: .
    links:
         - postgresql
         - rabbitmq
    volumes_from:
         - config

config:
    build: .
    dockerfile: dockerfiles/Dockerfile.config

postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes_from:
        - postgresql-data

postgresql-data:
    build: dockerfiles/postgresql-data/

nginx:
    build: .
    dockerfile: dockerfiles/Dockerfile.nginx
    links:
        - web-app

rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.5

celery-worker:
    build: .
    dockerfile: dockerfiles/Dockerfile.celery-worker
    links:
        - rabbitmq
```

`web-app` will use the default `Dockerfile` in the `project_root/`, all the other services will use a named dockerfile in a subdirectory (they can really be placed anywhere you want, they could be in the root as well).  As long as the `build` points at the root directory they will have access to all the files.

I would put your application configuration into a separate container and use `volumes_from` to make it available to the application, so that you can use the same stateless app container with different configurations.

I think this satisfies all your requirements.